# Changed SSL cerfificate - old certificate still in cache

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I had to change the SSL certificate from my website from a paid-certificate to a lets-encrypt certificate. Everything is working just fine but some users of the website still get an ssl-error (the old one expired). The problem is that they get the old certificate from the cache of their browsers.

How can i send a request to the browser to get the new ssl-cerficate or delete the old one in the cache? Is this even possible?

I am using wordpress.

Comment: as far as I know some browser do cash the ssl, but this is till the machine is restarted or the ssl cash state is cleared.

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver?

Comment: @AngelDeykov Do you have any source of this? Because I do not think browsers cache end certificates at all.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-SSL-State

Comment: @AngelDeykov I see no authoritative source in that link just someone giving its opinion. Links to source code or articles on the official website of the browsers would help, otherwise nothing is proved.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that they get the old certificate from the cache of their browsers.

Browsers don't cache leaf certificates.

I don't know anything about your exact setup but it is more likely that the old certificate is still in use like with different certificates on `www.example.com` and `example.com` and it depends on what the user visits.  Similar problems  are also known with different certificates on the IPv4 vs. IPv6 address, i.e. most users will visit the IPv4 site but some will visit the IPv6 site.

It might also be that you not only changed the certificate but also the IP address and the old site with the old certificate can still be found on the old IP address and some users still have the old IP address in their DNS cache.

Given that you don't provide the exact error message your users get it might also be a problem of a misconfigured server which fails to send intermediate certificates. While browsers try to work around such issues it is not possible in all cases. I recommend to check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and look for chain issuers or other problems.